# running twitter Bootstrap with Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I am planning to use twitter bootstrap-sass source code to build my web-application. I have downloaded the Sass source code from getBootstrap.com website. After downloading the code, when I run the `$ bower install bootstrap-sass` command from within the codebase. It created a directory called bower_components which has bootstrap-sass and jquery directory.

My question is am I doing the setup correctly? Also what is the next step. I want to customize the .scss files to generate the stylesheets. Please point me if I am going wrong or the appropriate reference to carry forward.

Comment: you don't need to download the sass source code manually of you are using bower

Comment: so I only need to run the bower install bootstrap-sass is it?

Comment: yes all the source files you need will be inside bower_components/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Yes. I have got the bower_components directory now. But I need a proper directory structure for my app. Also, how do I compile the scss files to css? How to organize the directory structures? Please help me. I am a novice in this area. By the way I am using IntelliJ Idea/Webstorm editor and have installed nodejs, bower etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it correctly though I would suggest you to install the bootstrap-sass using `--save`.

```
$ bower install bootstrap-sass --save
```

If you are interested in using gulp along with your app, then the following web page might be of a good reference

http://ericlbarnes.com/setting-gulp-bower-bootstrap-sass-fontawesome/

and if you want to just go ahead without gulp I would suggest you use

```
sass --force --update <source_directory>:<target_directory>
```

The source directory is the parent sass directory where your sass files are placed and the target directory is the final directory where all your generated css files would be complied and placed. So for instance if you want to compile the sass file `app/sass/abc.scss` and your target directory is `public/assets`, the use the above code as:

```
sass --force --update app/sass:public/assets.
```

This would generate two files called `abc.css` and `abc.map` in `public/assets` folder and you can link them in your web page(s).

Comment: could you please reply with your email address or twitter handle Sumit?

Comment: I was able to set up my development environment.  Thanks Sumit.

Comment: @Pradeep, glad to hear that I was of help and as you asked my email Id is sumit.srn@gmail.com